# Can't compile this Boost Algorithm example on GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, c++11, g++

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main(int, char **)
{
    string test = "h:help";

    vector<string> v;

    iter_split(v, test, first_finder("h:"));

    copy(v.begin(), v.end(), ostream_iterator<string>(cout, "\n"));
    return 0;
}
```

This simple code will not compile in GCC 4.6 using `-std=c++0x`; it will, however, compile fine in both an older compiler (4.2) and without the C++0x mode.

The error message output is:

```
In file included from /usr/include/boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp:15:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/algorithm/string.hpp:22,
                 from test.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/algorithm/string/iter_find.hpp: In function 'SequenceSequenceT& boost::algorithm::iter_split(SequenceSequenceT&, RangeT&, FinderT) [with SequenceSequenceT = std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >, RangeT = std::basic_string<char>, FinderT = boost::algorithm::detail::first_finderF<const char*, boost::algorithm::is_equal>]':
test.cpp:15:47:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/algorithm/string/iter_find.hpp:154:51: error: call of overloaded 'end(std::basic_string<char>&)' is ambiguous
/usr/include/boost/algorithm/string/iter_find.hpp:154:51: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/boost/range/end.hpp:145:56: note: typename boost::range_iterator<typename boost::remove_const<T>::type>::type boost::end(T&) [with T = std::basic_string<char>, typename boost::range_iterator<typename boost::remove_const<T>::type>::type = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >]
/usr/include/boost/range/end.hpp:156:61: note: typename boost::range_const_iterator<C>::type boost::end(const T&) [with T = std::basic_string<char>, typename boost::range_const_iterator<C>::type = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >]
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/range_access.h:78:5: note: decltype (__cont.end()) std::end(const _Container&) [with _Container = std::basic_string<char>, decltype (__cont.end()) = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >]
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/range_access.h:68:5: note: decltype (__cont.end()) std::end(_Container&) [with _Container = std::basic_string<char>, decltype (__cont.end()) = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >]
test.cpp:15:47:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/boost/algorithm/string/iter_find.hpp:162:39: error: call of overloaded 'begin(std::basic_string<char>&)' is ambiguous
/usr/include/boost/algorithm/string/iter_find.hpp:162:39: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/boost/range/begin.hpp:146:64: note: typename boost::range_iterator<typename boost::remove_const<T>::type>::type boost::begin(T&) [with T = std::basic_string<char>, typename boost::range_iterator<typename boost::remove_const<T>::type>::type = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >]
/usr/include/boost/range/begin.hpp:157:61: note: typename boost::range_const_iterator<C>::type boost::begin(const T&) [with T = std::basic_string<char>, typename boost::range_const_iterator<C>::type = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >]
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/range_access.h:58:5: note: decltype (__cont.begin()) std::begin(const _Container&) [with _Container = std::basic_string<char>, decltype (__cont.begin()) = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const char*, std::basic_string<char> >]
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.2/../../../../include/c++/4.6.2/bits/range_access.h:48:5: note: decltype (__cont.begin()) std::begin(_Container&) [with _Container = std::basic_string<char>, decltype (__cont.begin()) = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char*, std::basic_string<char> >]
```

Could this be a bug in GCC? Or is there something I could do to the code to fix this?

Comment: Works for me using MinGW (gcc 4.5.0).

Comment: What version of Boost? It's more likely a bug in an old version of Boost than a compiler bug...

Comment: Ohh I didn't think about that. BOOST_LIB_VERSION comes out to 1_34_1.

Comment: Boost 1.34.1 is nearly 4.5 years old; clearly C++11 support/compatibility was not a concern at the time. ;-] Boost 1.48.0 is current.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is merely a bug in the over-4-years-old version of Boost you're using. Upgrade to something more recent ([1.48.0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boost/files/boost/1.48.0/) is current) and your code will compile cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have installed boost-devel package

In Centos execute as root:

```
yum install boost-devel
```

then

```
root@centos6 /]# find / -name boost
/usr/include/boost
/usr/lib64/boost
[root@centos6 /]#
```